# Using two logging framework in same Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, slf4j

We have a common service module which  uses legacy log4J for logging. We need to use this module as dependency in a new Spring Boot application. In new application we are trying to set up SLF4J-Logback as logging framework which is recommended as Log4J is old however we are observing that the log messages are going to different log files. I think this is happening because our common module uses log4j while we are using logback in new module. Now which approach should we use ? Having log messages in two different files will make it difficult to read and debug issues. Shall i configure log4J and logback to use same file ? Is that safe ? Or we use log4j in new application as well and drop logback ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly recommend that you use a logging facade, what you already do with [SLF4J](https://www.slf4j.org/).

That means that [logback](https://logback.qos.ch/) in combination with `SLF4J` is a perfect choice. Thereby `SLF4J` severs as a simple facade for various logging frameworks. It allows to redirect log messages from legacy logging frameworks to behave as if they were made to the `SLF4J` API instead.

Adding the appropriate [briding module](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) (`log4j-over-slf4j`) to your classpath, should be everything you have to do for "installation".